# Stream URL to a local file with fs2

Tags: scala, fs2, cats-effect

Using fs2 (ver. 1.0.4) and cats-effect `IO`, I can stream an URL to a local file,

```
import concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

def download(spec: String, filename: String): Stream[IO, Unit] = 
  io.readInputStream((new URL(spec).openConnection.getInputStream), 4096, global, true)
    .through(io.file.writeAll(Paths.get(filename), global))
```

However, this code snippet does not return any information about the process when it is completed. On top of that, besides knowing the operation is successful or failure, I also want to know how many bytes are read if the operation is a success. I do not want to check the new file size to get this information. On the other hand, if the operation is a failure, I want to know what causes the failure.

I tried `attempt` but I could not resolve the subsequent steps to write the raw bytes to the new file. Please advise. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might want to play around with `observe`. I'm sure there's a better way to do this, but here's an example that might help you get unstuck:

Your original code that compiles and runs:

```
import fs2.io
import cats.effect.{IO, ContextShift}
import concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

import java.net.URL
import java.nio.file.Paths

object Example1 {
  implicit val contextShift: ContextShift[IO] = IO.contextShift(global)

  def download(spec: String, filename: String): fs2.Stream[IO, Unit] =
    io.readInputStream[IO](IO(new URL(spec).openConnection.getInputStream), 4096, global, closeAfterUse=true)
      .through(io.file.writeAll(Paths.get(filename), global))

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    download("https://isitchristmas.com/", "/tmp/christmas.txt")
      .compile.drain.unsafeRunSync()
  }
}
```

Using observe to count bytes:

```
import fs2.io
import cats.effect.{IO, ContextShift}
import concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

import java.net.URL
import java.nio.file.Paths

object Example2 {
  implicit val contextShift: ContextShift[IO] = IO.contextShift(global)

  final case class DlResults(bytes: Long)

  def download(spec: String, filename: String): fs2.Stream[IO, DlResults] =
    io.readInputStream[IO](IO(new URL(spec).openConnection.getInputStream), 4096, global, closeAfterUse = true)
      .observe(io.file.writeAll(Paths.get(filename), global))
      .fold(DlResults(0L)) { (r, _) => DlResults(r.bytes + 1) }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    download("https://isitchristmas.com/", "/tmp/christmas.txt")
      .compile
      .fold(()){ (_, r) => println(r)}
      .unsafeRunSync()
  }
}
```

Output:

```
> DlResults(42668)
```

Comment: Thanks. You gave me some ideas to continue. My suggestions, `DlResults` is not required because you can ` .fold(0L) { (r, _) => r.bytes + 1` unless you have other reasons not to change. And finish it with `.compile.last.unsafeRunSync().foreach(println)`

Comment: Yeah DlResults would be more useful if you had multiple pieces of information to return. And `compile.last` definitely looks better than my folding nonsense. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution in terms of `Resource` and `IO` and, @codenoodle suggestion.

## Update #1

`Resource` is removed because it is redundant when used with FS2 and complicates the code.

```
import java.io.{
  FileNotFoundException,
  FileOutputStream,
  InputStream,
  OutputStream
}

import java.net.URL

import cats.effect.{ExitCode, IO, IOApp, Resource}
import cats.implicits._
import fs2._

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

object LetStream extends IOApp {
  override def run(args: List[String]): IO[ExitCode] = {
    def write(source: IO[InputStream], target: IO[OutputStream]) =
      io.readInputStream(source, 4096, global)
        .chunks
        .flatMap(Stream.chunk)
        .observe(io.writeOutputStream(target, global))
        .chunks
        .fold(0L)((acc, chunk) => acc + chunk.size)

    write(IO(new FileOutputStream("image.jpg")), 
      IO(new URL("http://localhost:8080/images/helloworld.jpg")
            .openConnection
            .getInputStream))
      .use(_.compile.toList)
      .flatMap(size => 
        IO(println(s"Written ${size.head} bytes")) *> IO(ExitCode.Success))      
      .recover {
        case t: FileNotFoundException =>
          IO(println(s"Not found, ${t.getMessage}")) *> IO(ExitCode.Error)
        case err =>
          IO(println(err.getMessage)) *> IO(ExitCode.Error)
      }
  }
}
```