# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError While receiving HTTP response

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, azure-databricks

I have below function to call API and that returns the text from response body.

```
def GetResponse(headers: Map[String, String], url: String): String = {
    
    val obj: URL = new URL(url)
    val con: HttpsURLConnection = obj.openConnection().asInstanceOf[HttpsURLConnection]
    var iStream: InputStream = null
  
    try {
      var output: String = null
    
      con.setRequestMethod("GET")
      headers.foreach { case (k, v) => {
        con.setRequestProperty(k, v)
      }
      }
      val httpResponseCode = con.getResponseCode
      
      if (httpResponseCode == 200 || httpResponseCode == 206) {
        iStream = con.getInputStream
        output = Source.fromInputStream(iStream).getLines().mkString("\n")
      }
      output
    }
    catch {
      case exception: Exception => throw new Exception("Http Handler exception in GetHttpResponse", exception)
    }
  finally{
    if(iStream != null){
      iStream.close()
    }
    con.disconnect()
  }
  }
```

I have 6GB CSV file on blob storage and I am trying to get the data bytes by bytes i.e. first 0 to 500MB, then 501MB to 1000MB etc.

removing unnecessary code from below block. In short, below loop gets executed 4 times, 500MB X 4 and exactly fails after importing 2GB data. How exactly we can flush the data here? We are simply calling the function and saving data in data frame. We are not appending data to variable, right?

```
for(i <- 1 to chunkNum) {
      println(i)
              println("BeforeResponse")
              val response =  GetResponse(headers, "https://myblobstorage.blob.core.windows.net/test/test6gb.csv")
              println("AfterResponse")
              dfRestAPI = dfRestAPI.union(Seq((response,currentDate)).toDF("Chunk","InsertedDate"))
            }
```

Result:

[image: ErrorMessage]

Comment: You are doing exactly that. Your `dfRestAPI` is going to contain the all chunks of the file.

Comment: No, sorry. Union of dataframe is not the issue. If I comment that line, I still get the error. Something is wrong with the GetResponse function. It keeps on storing the data in memory. Looking for some workaround like flush the data, clear memory etc.

Comment: OR keep on saving the data to Databricks file system / disk.

Comment: Why don't you use a `Stream`? See here an example `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55561104/stream-url-to-a-local-file-with-fs2`

Comment: All local objects are considered garbage after each iteration of for loop. So, your `val response = GetResponse(...)` should not have any impact, unless you are leaking this `response` out of the loop iteration. The only place where you are doin that is in this `dfRestAPI = dfRestAPI.union ...` line.